Using a queue and a counting semaphore for resource management
I'm coding in a embedded environment with FreeRTOS and an STM32. As a POC I made the following code :
void producerTask1(void *pvParameters) {
    int dataToSend = 1;
    static bool necessary = false; 
    while(1) {
        // Take the counting semaphore before sending data to the queue
        xSemaphoreTake(countSemaphore, portMAX_DELAY);
        // Send data to the queue
        if (xQueueSend(myQueue, &dataToSend, portMAX_DELAY) == pdTRUE) {
            // Successfully sent data to the queue
        }
        // Interrupt consumer if necessary
        if(necessary)
        {
          vTaskNotifyGive(consumerTask);
        }
        // Simulate production delay
        vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
        necessary != necessary;
        xSemaphoreGive(countSemaphore);
    }
}

void producerTask2(void *pvParameters) {
    int dataToSend = 2;
    static bool necessary = true;
    while(1) {
        // Take the counting semaphore before sending data to the queue
        xSemaphoreTake(countSemaphore, portMAX_DELAY);
        // Send data to the queue
        if (xQueueSend(myQueue, &dataToSend, portMAX_DELAY) == pdTRUE) {
            // Successfully sent data to the queue
        }
        if(necessary)
        {
          vTaskNotifyGive(consumerTask);
        }
        // Simulate production delay
        vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(1500));
        necessary != necessary;
        xSemaphoreGive(countSemaphore);
    }
}

int isThereDataWaitingInMyQueue() {
    return uxQueueMessagesWaiting(myQueue) > 0;
}

int areAllSemaphoreFree() {
    // Check if the counting semaphore is at its maximum value
    return uxSemaphoreGetCount(countSemaphore) == 10;
}

int actionToDo() {
    // Implement the logic to determine if an action needs to be done
    return 1; // Placeholder for demonstration
}

void consumerTask(void *pvParameters) {
    int receivedData;
    while(1) {
        do {
            if (xQueueReceive(myQueue, &receivedData, portMAX_DELAY) == pdTRUE) {
                // Process received data
                printf("Received data: %d\n", receivedData);
            }
        } while(isThereDataWaitingInMyQueue());

        // Wait until all semaphores are free
        while(!areAllSemaphoreFree()) {
            vTaskDelay(1);
        }

        // Perform actions when the queue is empty
        while(!isThereDataWaitingInMyQueue() && actionToDo()) {
            // Perform actions and check if I was interrupted
            // if interrupted we'll exit this loop and go back to 
            // waiting on queue
            ulTaskNotifyTake(pdTRUE, 500);

        }
    }
}

void main(void) {
    // Create the queue and the counting semaphore
    myQueue = xQueueCreate(10, sizeof(int));
    countSemaphore = xSemaphoreCreateCounting(10, 10);

    // Create producer tasks
    xTaskCreate(producerTask1, "Producer1", 1000, NULL, 1, NULL);
    xTaskCreate(producerTask2, "Producer2", 1000, NULL, 1, NULL);

    // Create the consumer task
    xTaskCreate(consumerTask, "Consumer", 1000, NULL, 1, NULL);

    // Start the scheduler
    vTaskStartScheduler();

    // Infinite loop (the code should never reach this point)
    while(1);
}

Is it ok to use a counting semaphore this way ?
From the examples I've seen before and the code database that I have I've never seen counting semaphore used this way, so I thought I might be doing something wrong.
I asked ChatGPT his opinion but it's like talking to a wall :/

It's not clear why you would want a semaphore here; just having the queue seems like it would be enough. If you try to push into a full queue it will block until there is space.

It is because in the consumer tasks, where I perform actions I actually check if I received a TaskNotification (from the producer task)  which would then mean I have to stop the actions and go back to waiting on the queue.
I will edit my first message to be more clear

You only have two producers, each of which takes and then immediately gives the counting semaphore. It will never be taken 10 times simultaneously. Your design seems misguided. Let the queue do the counting, you don't need a semaphore.

In other words, your xSemaphoreTake() will never block. So what's the point in it?

Yes but if the priority of my consumer task is higher than the producer tasks I will then go to the consumer task as soon as data is transmitted. And without a check of my counting semaphore in the middle a producer task would interrupt itself. Yes it does feel odd but I just can't put my finger on why :/

Your code would make (slightly) more sense if you took the semaphore in the producers, and gave it in your consumer. But you don't. The producers both take and give it.

It feels like you're tying yourself in knots here, an X/Y problem. A 10 entry queue and a 10 valued counting semaphore. And task notifications. Re-think what you're trying to do. I bet there's a very simple solution, that probably requires nothing more than a queue.
